# Progress bar overflow div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing progress bar I added div inside bar but at `0%` and `100%` value is overflow and while moving also looks like a doubt after reached the point then shows full width.

Expected output: 
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function progressbar() {
        $('.iva_progress_bar').each(function() {

            var totalreviews = 1540;

            var percent = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width');

            $(this).find('.percentage').append(percent + '%');
            $(this).find('.bar_color').animate({
                  width: percent + '%'
             }, 1500);

            var a = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width'); 
            var ur = ( a/ 100 ) * totalreviews;

            var usersReview = Math.floor(ur);
            $(this).find('.users').append(usersReview); 
        });   
    }

    progressbar();
});
```

```css
/* progress bar */
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_title {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_wrap {
    flex-basis: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_color {
    position: relative;
    padding: 18px 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #3379b7;
}
.testimonial_block2 .percentage {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 6px;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial_block2 .users {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #777777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial_block2">

    <!-- progress bar -->

    <div class="iva_progress_bar">
        <div class="bar_title">5 REVIEWS</div>
        <div class="bar_wrap">
            <span class="bar_color" data-width="0">
                <div class="percentage"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="users"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="iva_progress_bar">
        <div class="bar_title">4 REVIEWS</div>
        <div class="bar_wrap">
            <span class="bar_color" data-width="100">
                <div class="percentage"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="users"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="iva_progress_bar">
        <div class="bar_title">3 REVIEWS</div>
        <div class="bar_wrap">
            <span class="bar_color" data-width="3">
                <div class="percentage"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="users"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="iva_progress_bar">
        <div class="bar_title">2 REVIEWS</div>
        <div class="bar_wrap">
            <span class="bar_color" data-width="6">
                <div class="percentage"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="users"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="iva_progress_bar">
        <div class="bar_title">1 REVIEWS</div>
        <div class="bar_wrap">
            <span class="bar_color" data-width="11">
                <div class="percentage"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="users"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function who calculate the width of your element percentage and make the left with this percent.

i have create this. you can modify this:

```
if(percent >= 88){
  perce = 100 - percent
  $(this).find(".percentage").css({left:(88-perce) + "%"})
}else{
  $(this).find(".percentage").css({left:(percent) + "%"})
}
```

**Full code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function progressbar() {
        $('.iva_progress_bar').each(function() {

            var totalreviews = 1540;

            var percent = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width');
        
            
            if(percent >= 88){
              perce = 100 - percent
              $(this).find(".percentage").css({left:(88-perce) + "%"})
            }else{
              $(this).find(".percentage").css({left:(percent) + "%"})
            }
            
            $(this).find('.percentage').append(percent + '%');
            $(this).find('.bar_color').animate({
                  width: percent + '%'
             }, 1500);

            var a = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width'); 
            var ur = ( a/ 100 ) * totalreviews;
           
            var usersReview = Math.floor(ur);
            $(this).find('.users').append(usersReview); 
            
        });   
    }
   
    progressbar();
});
```

```css
/* progress bar */
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_title {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_wrap {
    flex-basis: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_color {
 position: relative;
    padding: 18px 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #3379b7;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.testimonial_block2 .percentage {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 6px;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial_block2 .users {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #777777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial_block2">

     <!-- progress bar -->

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">5 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="0">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">4 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="100">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">3 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span  class="bar_color" data-width="3">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">2 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="6">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">1 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="11">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: visible !important;` will fix this issue

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function progressbar() {
        $('.iva_progress_bar').each(function() {

            var totalreviews = 1540;

            var percent = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width');

            $(this).find('.percentage').append(percent + '%');
            $(this).find('.bar_color').animate({
                  width: percent + '%'
             }, 1500);

            var a = $(this).find('.bar_color').attr('data-width'); 
            var ur = ( a/ 100 ) * totalreviews;
           
            var usersReview = Math.floor(ur);
            $(this).find('.users').append(usersReview); 
        });   
    }
   
    progressbar();
});
```

```css
/* progress bar */
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_title {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_wrap {
    flex-basis: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.testimonial_block2 .iva_progress_bar .bar_color {
 position: relative;
    padding: 18px 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #3379b7;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.testimonial_block2 .percentage {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 6px;
    right: -20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial_block2 .users {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #777777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial_block2">

     <!-- progress bar -->

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">5 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="0">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">4 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="100">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">3 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span  class="bar_color" data-width="3">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">2 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="6">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="iva_progress_bar">
      <div class="bar_title">1 REVIEWS</div>
      <div class="bar_wrap">
       <span class="bar_color" data-width="11">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="users"></div>
     </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: see at `0%` div is overflow i dont want like that it should be inside the bar. as shown in fig

Comment: i don't think this is possible with css only

Comment: using jquery? i don't have a problem with jquery also.